# Javascript - image button change on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code, which I got from this site, which is confirmed as working. Not for me. Don't mind the div tag.

[image]

Paths are good, it's showing images in DW, but nothing happens after clicking on image on website...

Also, heres the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Behavioral Meta Data -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container" class="container">
    <ul id="scene" class="scene border fill">
      <li id="Par_3" class="layer expand-width" data-depth="0.25"><img src="../Img/Par_3.svg" alt="Gallery"></li>
      <li id="Par_2" class="layer expand-width" data-depth="0.20"><img src="../Img/Par_2.svg" alt="Grass_1"></li>
      <li id="Par_25" class="layer expand-width" data-depth="0.20"><img src="../Img/Par_2.5.svg" alt="About me"></li>
      <li id="Par_1" class="layer expand-width" data-depth="0.15"><img src="../Img/Par_1.svg" alt="Grass_2"></li>
      <li id="Par_15" class="layer expand-width" data-depth="0.15"><img src="../Img/Par_1.5.svg" alt="Contact"></li>
      <li id="Par_0" class="layer expand-width" data-depth="0.10"><img src="../Img/Par_0.svg" alt="Rock"></li>
      <li id="Logo" class="layer expand-width"  data-depth="0.05"><img src="../Img/Logo.svg" alt="Logo"></li>
    </ul>

    <img alt="" src="../Img/Click_u.svg" id="cm" onclick="changeImage()"  />

  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->

  <script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.getElementById("cm").src == "../Img/Click_u.svg") 
        {
            document.getElementById("cm").src = "../Img/Click_ch.svg";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("cm").src = "../Img/Click_u.svg";
        }
    }
</script>

  <script src="Parallax.js"></script>
  <script>

  var scene = document.getElementById('scene');
  var parallax = new Parallax(scene);

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code in text not pictures.

Comment: what site? there's a missing link. also please dont add code as image.

Comment: do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById("cm").src)`

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, `.src` returns not only the relative path (`../Img/Click_u.svg`) but the entire path (`http://www.yourwebsite.com/images/Img/Click_u.svg`).

So that `if` condition will never be true, and it will never change the image.

[image: Example screenshot]

Perhaps try something along the lines of

```
if (document.getElementById("cm").src.indexOf("Click_u.svg") != -1)
```

To check if the snippet "Click_u.svg" can be found inside the larger string `src`.

Or use

```
document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("src")`
```

and it will return you the exact value of the attribute (which is the relative path)

---

The code that should work on your case:

```
if (document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("src") == "../Img/Click_u.svg")
{
    document.getElementById("cm").src = "../Img/Click_ch.svg";
}
else 
{
    document.getElementById("cm").src = "../Img/Click_u.svg";
}
```

For some weird reason, there seems to be an invisible character just at the end of the `getAttribute` method. No clue as to why, but if you, reader, are willing to use this code, please retype it instead of copy-pasting.

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

That's a bug for another time

Comment: any way to set this to use relative path ?

Comment: As far as I know, `src` won't ever return the relative path :\ I could be wrong though
EDIT: Nevermind! I just thought of a way haha. Using `.getAttribute("src")`, you can fetch the relative path

Comment: Should it be something like this ? Because its still not working for me...

 <img alt="" src="../Img/Click_u.svg" id="cm" onclick="changeImage()"  />
    
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->

  <script language="javascript">
    function changeImage() {

        if (document.document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("../Img/Click_u.svg"); 
        {
            document.document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("../Img/Click_ch.svg");
        }
        else 
        {
            document.document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("../Img/Click_u.svg");
        }
    }

Comment: You're using `document.document` there. And to set the source, you still use `.src = "..."`, but to get it, you can use the `.getAttribute()`. I'll edit the answer to include some code that might work.

Comment: Try to do what [epascarello](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello) said and `console.log(document.getElementById("cm").getAttribute("src"));`, then check the console to see what it gives you.

Comment: I do, get an error. Is there any other way to swap images upon img click ?

Comment: What error do you get? And this is (or should be) the easiest way to swap images. Other methods would include changing element classes and such

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token "  It seems as if I am getting more and more screwed...

Comment: That error is expected when the element doesn't exist... Which is strange. Check if `console.log(document.getElementById("cm"));` returns `null` or the actual element

Comment: I dont know... I got lost it in actually.

Comment: I lost my nerves and I am really pissed off with this. Something as simple as button and its not working for 4 hours. I might return to it tomorrow, but atm I am seriously pissed off about this...

Comment: There seems to be some weird invisible character [here](http://i.imgur.com/W3PwwI7.png) which is causing the problem. It must be something related to Stackoverflow formatting, idk. Try typing the code instead of copy pasting, and check if it works.

Comment: Its not just Stackoverflow. I've also tried w3schools, youtube, some forums... They might have used the entire path, hence the reason its not working....

Comment: So i rechecked on youtube. Everyone moves pictures into same foler as index and .js . But there has to be a way to do this leaving images in img folder...

Comment: Honestly, I just typed it manually, the code you have posted. No change, no success...

Comment: Damn... I honestly don't know, then ;\